# Passing own class object as parameter in python method

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I happened to come across a code which uses the following:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        .....

    def ex_m1(self, exinst):
        .....
        exinst.ex_m2(exinst)

    def ex_m2(self, exinst):
        self.inst = exinst
        .....
        self.inst.ex_m3()

    def ex_m3(self):
        .....


test = example()
test.ex_m1(test)
```

What does the author of the code intend to achieve here? Isn't the above same as the following?

```
class example:
    def __init__(self):
        .....

    def ex_m1(self):
        .....
        self.ex_m2()

    def ex_m2(self):
        .....
        self.ex_m3()

    def ex_m3(self):
        .....


test = example()
test.ex_m1()
```

If they're not the same, how are they different?

Comment: What is purpose pass `self` to member function?

Comment: Well, for one thing, the second example doesn't set the `inst` instance attribute. Was there a stated purpose for the original code?

Comment: @glibdud It's just a code I came across in the lab. Most likely meant for regular execution. I want to understand how that's going to make a difference.

Comment: You don't understand the difference between assigning a value to an attribute and not doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The original code does some work on a second instance of the class stored in self.exinst (not on the current instance itself) whereas your revised version works only with the current instance.

This is the kind of pattern you could see in linked lists.